# Check if a string is an objective c method declaration

Tags: objective-c, regex, string, parsing, nsstring

I am trying to write a simple method declaration formatting program and I need to validate if the string is actually an objective c method declaration.

Are there some kind of build in functionality to do that or maybe a regex command to validate such things, or do I need to implement my own parser for such a case?

for now I have trimmed the string for white spaces and converted it to lower case, so it is easier to validate, using for loops. For instance in the following code, I can check if the substring "(void)" occurs to determine that it is a void function, but that doesn't do the job. There must be a better way.

```
-(BOOL)isVoidMethod:(NSString*)method
{
    /* Remove white spaces and lower case the method */
    [self convertToParseMethod:method];

    BOOL isVoid = NO;

    if ([method rangeOfString:@"(void)"].location != NSNotFound) {
        isVoid = YES;
    } else if ( [method rangeOfString:@"(ibaction)"].location != NSNotFound ) {
        isVoid = YES;
    }

    return isVoid;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't that way, as a returns type isn't necessary (implicitly defaults to `id`), making this: `-doSomething:(id) argument` a totally valid method signature. You only see it in really archaic objc though.

Comment: Seeing also as `IBAction` is a macro which translates to `void`, for any preprocessed file you shouldn't have that issue. You really should take a step back and analyze exactly what you are trying to do, and why can't a compiler do that work for you?

Comment: I would do this by invoking llvm with execl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this correctly/precisely is *hard*. While a method declaration doesn't look too complicated as it potentially contains any type declaration possible in C - and a common quiz question is "What does this C declaration mean?" - the syntax is actually quite involved. Compound that with, to my knowledge, there being no published BNF for Objective-C (though you might find one in the Clang source), and you've got a challenge on your hands.

So you do need to write your own parser, but you can probably tackle it in a fuzzy/imprecise way - assume the input is valid and "tokenise" it fuzzily based, say, not on what you expect but on what you don't expect - so an argument type is not a C type declaration but just an parenthesised string which might contain other balanced parentheses, and you can lex that by counting the parentheses.

Have fun!

Comment: hehe alright, I actually started parsing the string now, and with small hacks maybe I will get there :) Thanks for the answer!